# MySQL rollup when some columns include NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, rollup

I have a dataset where it is somewhat common for fields to have `NULL` as a valid value. This causes an issue when I want to use the `ROLLUP` operator in MySQL, as I can't distinguish between the `NULL` values it generates as part of its subtotals/totals and the actual `NULL` values in the data.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(car_score, "Total") AS car_score,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS volume
FROM cars_table
GROUP BY
  car_score ASC WITH ROLLUP;
```

This provides me with the following table:

```
cars_score   |  volume
---------------------------
Total        |  500
1            |  100
2            |  200
3            |  300
4            |  400
5            |  500
Total        |  2000
```

when I'd like it to be:

```
cars_score   |  volume
---------------------------
NULL         |  500
1            |  100
2            |  200
3            |  300
4            |  400
5            |  500
Total        |  2000
```

This is a simple example, and it becomes more frustrating once I have multiple dimensions for the `ROLLUP`. The reason I can't just change the `NULL` value before to something else is that I also need to be able to aggregate the data in other parts of the application, so having a proper `NULL` is important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to wrap with a subquery which first replaces the actual `NULL` values which indicate missing data.  Then, use `COALESCE()` as you were to replace the `NULL` from the rollup with the string `"Total"`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.car_score, 'Total') AS car_score,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS volume
FROM
(
    SELECT COALESCE(cars_score, 99) AS car_score, id
    FROM cars_table
) t
GROUP BY t.car_score WITH ROLLUP
```

Here I have used `99` as a placeholder to indicate car scores which were missing.  You can use any placeholder you want, other than `NULL`.

Comment: This works great! The only issue is that it will create more work for me as I am dynamically creating the SQL, but it is a good problem to have. Thanks!